# click a button inside a form that is an image

Tags: ruby, mechanize

When I do this

```
pp form
```

I get

```
{buttons [imagebutton:0x49cc436 type: image name: go value: ]}>
```

How do I submit when the button is a image? Since this won't work

```
button = form.image_with(:class => "go")
```

and the css

```
<input type="image" src="/images/btn_search_3.gif" name="go" class="go" alt="Sök">
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
form.submit form.button
```

Make an effort to look at the mechanize docs first before posting questions please.